# Relational Databases - Best Way to Store Accumulating Data?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm trying to figure out the best way to keep track of data that accumulates over time.

Say I have sports players who score goals each week. I can use a `goals` column to store a player's goal count and update this value when needs be:

```
Player
    id
    name 
    goals
```

That looks to work fine, but, I'm thinking about what to do at the end of the season. I can either keep counting, or I can decide that what I'm really interested are the players' `goals_this_season`.

I don't want to forget about that glorious season, is my best bet to create another table to record the goals from past seasons?

Should I therefore completely get rid of the `goals_this_season` column in my players table? Or should this decision be dictated on my business logic? ie. If I'm much more interested in `goals_this_season` should it remain a part of the players table so that I don't need to access two tables every time I want a player's `goals_this_season`?

```
SeasonGoals
    id
    season_year 
    player_id == Player.id
    goals
```

What if I scale to `goals_this_week`, or `goals_this_game`? Is this still the best idea? Are there alternatives?

#### Summary

- Should I store historical data, relating to an object, in a separate table as outlined?
- Should whether I have a `Player.goals_this_season` column be decided by how I intend to use the database? Or should it be part of the `SeasonGoals` table?

Comment: Do you have a `game` table which identifies games? If it were me, I would store each goal _individually_ along with the id of the game it occurred in, inside a join table called `games_goals` which has a `player_id`, `game_id` and a timestamp if you have one, which represents each goal event. Then you can perform any aggregation on them, query them based on their dates  (seasons) etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski think I would have a games table, so yes could do that. Do you think this is preferable over Dan Farrell's answer? Is what you're suggesting another example of normalisation?

Comment: We're essentially describing the same thing. @MichaelBerkowski is probably right in saying that the table would hold a game ID as well as a timestamp and a player_id.

Comment: @Pete Dan and I are suggesting something very similar (both are normalization) but his suggestion doesn't account for games - just players and goals.  I would expand that suggestion such that 3 tables are involved: `player`, `game`, `games_goals` (or `players_games_goals` or something).

Comment: Sounds sensible, however, what if I have many statistics other than goals? (shots on target, fouls, etc) Is this still the best idea, or is there such a thing as having too many tables?

Comment: @Pete Depends how granular you want to be. If you really only care about events happening in a game, you could have a table which has `player_id, game_id` then the other events like `goals,shots,fouls` and increment them within the same row. So that gets you statistics at the _game_ level per player, but you wouldn't as easily know the _exact timestamp_ of those events if that extra information matters to you.

Comment: @Pete OR.... You have a `player_game_events` table which has a player_id, game_id, timestamp, and `event_type` which says whether it was a `"goal","shot","foul","etc"`.  That's probably how I would approach it - so all the events are in one table but differentiated with a column to identify their type.

Comment: @michaelBerkowski I think in this case I'm only interested on a game level. Timestamps are more information than I need, so incrementing within the same row sounds best. Next scenario, what if the sport has different stats for players with different roles (like in netball or American football). Should I include all the stats as columns in a single table and except that some will always be left blank, or should I create a table for each type of player? A attacker_game_stats table etc

Comment: @Pete Any consideration of creating multiple _similar_ tables should raise red flags. But one "wide" table with lots of irrelevant stats in columns doesn't make great sense either. Instead, it makes the case for the method I described above, with a row per stat event (with or w/o a timestamp).  But if you'll have a diverse set of possible events, that warrants yet another table to describe them.So instead of strings `"goal","shot","foul","etc"` you would store a `player_id,game_id,stat_event_id` and in a new table for stat events you flesh out the stats...

Comment: `stat_event_id,description` where the id is a number and description is `"shots on goal".  From here, it's easier to create views which perform all the necessary aggregation for different sports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is normalize the data.  There is a one-to-many relationship between players and goals, so normalization demands that each goal should correspond to a row in a `player_goals` table.  Timestamp your goals and then use grouping queries ( possibly caching the results in a summary table ) to get goals per period of time, whether that be days, months, years, etc.